# Teams /tools page — Oops! Something bad happened!

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

When navigating to the [private Stack Overflow Moderators Teams moderators tools page](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/tools) (only meant to be accessible to users who are moderator on at least one SE site), I get

> Oops! Something Bad Happened

I expected to get either

> This page requires more privileges

Or maybe an Error 404, but Something Bad Happened sounds... bad.

Comment: works for me... Maybe you should earn 10K on the team?

Comment: @Shog9 Perhaps so, but then it should still tell me I need more privileges.

Comment: It's *trying* to - it's returning 403 behind the scenes (just as it does on any other site when you lack permission), and then the facade that SO provides to the Team is interpreting that as an error and tossing its cookies.